# <picture> tag doesn't work

Tags: html

I found out today about the `<picture>` tag, which allows for multiple image sources for an `<img>`. I followed [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp) on w3schools

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

And I implemented it as such:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width:768px)" srcset="img/keyclubsmall.png">
  <source srcset="img/key.png">
  <a href = "/"><img src = "img/key.png"></a>
</picture>
```

**Problem**: when I shrink the screen width to less than `768px`, `key.png` is still used, ignoring `keyclubsmall.png`, which `<picture>` was supposed to switch to. What am I doing wrong, and what needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem: `<a>` needs to wrap the entire `<picture>`, since `<img>` is no longer the sole component to the image.

```
<a href = "/">
  <picture>
    <source media="(max-width:768px)" srcset="img/keyclubsmall.png">
    <source srcset="img/key.png">
    <img src = "img/key.png">
  </picture>
</a>
```